# Compiler error when building Qt

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, nmake

I am trying to build Qt myself. I checked out everything and want to run configure now. The Visual Studio 2013 compiler is in PATH but I get this error

```
C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\Qt>configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examp
les -nomake tests -opengl desktop
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\Qt\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -developer-build -
opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop
Please wait while bootstrapping configure ...
<srcbase> = C:/Users/Philipp/Desktop/Qt/qtbase
<outbase> = C:/Users/Philipp/Desktop/Qt/qtbase

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -Yc -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -MT -W3 -GR -EHsc -w34100 -w34189
-DUNICODE -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_LITE_COMPO
NENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -D_CRT
_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_BUILD_CONFIGURE -DCOMMERCIAL_VERSION
 -I"..\..\include" -I"..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\include\QtCore\5.2.0" -I"..
\..\include\QtCore\5.2.0\QtCore" -I"C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\Qt\qtbase\tools\sha
red" -I"C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\Qt\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fpconfigure_
pch.pch -Foconfigure_pch.obj -TP C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\Qt\qtbase\tools\config
ure\configure_pch.h
configure_pch.h
c:\users\philipp\desktop\qt\qtbase\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglob
al.h(46) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file
 or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiler itself in the `PATH` variable is not enough, it needs to know where include files and libraries are located.

Check vc++ has `PATH` variables it uses defined (at least both `INCLUDE` and `LIBPATH`).

If not you have two options:

- Run `configure` from *Developer Command Prompt* (you can find it in the Visual Studio Tools program group).
- From any command prompt window run `VcVars32.bat` batch file (or `VsVars32.bat`) located in `Common7\Tools` folder under VS installation directory.

Comment: Running `configure` from the Developer Command Prompt doesn't work (generic couldn't find command error).